# firebase update database after uploading image to storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, upload, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React-native, Redux.

npm "firebase": "^4.6.0"
    "react-native-fetch-blob" for blobing image

I am trying to upload an image and then add the image URL to the database using firebase.

I can upload an image to storage or update data in the database, bat I cannot do them both.

after uploading an image I call to update data and getting no response (success/failure)

**Both of the functions working 100% alone, I cannot call them one after another.**
Do I need to do clear? reset? and if so, how?

Upload image:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();...
db.collection("reports").doc(uId).collection("user-reports")
        .add({
            "title": "report title...",
            "discription": "discription..."})
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Document successfully written!");
            dispach({
                type: types.FIREBASE_REPORT_ADD,
                payload: "Added Report"
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", err);
        });
```

upload data:

```
const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${uId}/${CREATION_TIME}`);
return (dispach) => {

fs.readFile(imagePath, 'base64')
    .then((data) => {
        //console.log(data);
        return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
    })
    .then((blob) => {
        uploadBlob = blob;
        return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
    })
.then(() => {
    uploadBlob.close()
    return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
})
.then((url) => {
    console.log("some url:",url)
    dispach({
            type: types.FIREBASE_REPORT_IMAGE_UPLOADED,
            payload:url
        })
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("Blob err: ",error);
    dispach({
            type: types.FIREBASE_REPORT_IMAGE_UPLOADED,
            payload:null
        })
});
}
```

Comment: There should be a callback for upload completion to storage.  Use that to write the file's url to the database.  This is a pretty common practice.  Is there is a problem with that?  Can you be more specific?  Maybe show your code?

Comment: Are you using the SDK that firebase bring?

Comment: I am using firebase": "^4.6.0" "react-native-fetch-blob"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with living the "BLOB" and uploading my Image with base64.
like so:

```
ref.putString(message, 'base64').then(function(snapshot) {
```

console.log('Uploaded a base64 string!');
});

working so smooth